# How to execute a matlab code for different files?

Tags: matlab, csv

I have this matlab code who read and load my csv files

```
> `%% Initialize variables.
filename = 'C:\Users\loubn\Documents\MATLAB\test\fichier1.csv';
delimiter = ',';
to the end of the code
```

and it work perfectly , i want to execute this script for the others .csv files (fichier2,fichier3 ....... fichieri) on the test folder

Comment: Show what you have tried, where your problem is, in essence a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normally it should work direktly if you change the filename string.

```
filename = 'C:\Users\loubn\Documents\MATLAB\test\fichier2.csv'
```

Have you tried that already? Or is there some other kind of problem?

Comment: thank you for your answer .. yes it work but i need it automatically and not to modifie it manually because i have lots of files

Comment: Ah, I understand now! The way Brice answered your Question should work perfectly. 
The data of each fichier is then stored in filename{ii}. So if you want to use the data from the first fichier then you just type filename{1}. (just in case you need to know)

Answer (score 1):

You may simply store all the file names into a cell array and then use a for loop:

```
allFilenames = {'C:\...\file1.csv','C:\...\file2.csv','C:\...\file3.csv'};
for ii=1:length(allFilenames)
    filename=allFilenames{ii};
    % Do something with variable "filename"
end
```

Another option is to store them into a structure array (such as what the `dir` function provides).

```
testDir = 'C:\Users\...\test';
template = '*.csv';
allFiles = dir(fullfile(testDir,template));

% This will produce an array of structures with the file name in field "name" 
for ii=1:length(allFiles)
    %Combine directory and file name into an absolute path to the file
    filename=fullfile(testDir,allFiles(ii).name); 
    % Then do something with variable "filename"
end
```